# How to remove square braces [] from an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, object, split

**Consider the following object**

```
var obj1=[
    {
      'Charles Byers': 'Industrials',
      'David Smith': 'Industrials',
      'Joe Evans': 'Industrials',
      'Larry Young': 'Industrials',
      'Martin Hammond': 'Industrials',
      'William Green': 'Industrials'
    }
  ]
```

I need to **remove the starting and ending square brackets [] without converting this into a string** Like,

```
var obj1=
          {'Charles Byers': 'Industrials',
          'David Smith': 'Industrials',
          'Joe Evans': 'Industrials',
          'Larry Young': 'Industrials',
          'Martin Hammond': 'Industrials',
          'William Green': 'Industrials'}
```

**How can I possibly achieve this?**

*NOTE: The size and contents of the object might change.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the entries and map new objects from a single key/value pair.

```js
const
    object = { 'Charles Byers': 'Industrials', 'David Smith': 'Industrials', 'Joe Evans': 'Industrials', 'Larry Young': 'Industrials', 'Martin Hammond': 'Industrials', 'William Green': 'Industrials' },
    result = Object
        .entries(object)
        .map(keyValue => Object.fromEntries([keyValue]));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: The key and value names may change. What can I do at that time? @Nina Scholz

Comment: do you have an example? what is changing? please add any additional information to the question.

Comment: This is the format. The contents of the object might change. I need to split them up. @Nina Scholz